# How to automatically scale graph to fit it on Y axis?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I have almost finished Line graph, and I want to fit screen it on Y axis. MIN\MAX Peak values should touch top and bottom corner of the graph. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find minimum and maximum in your `DataSet` and use

```
chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0f);
chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaximum(100f);
```

to set the boundaries accordingly.